# How to increase for loop performance in Python

Tags: python-3.x, concurrency, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a for loop where there are a series of operations performed but one method in particular I discovered takes about 44% of the time for the entire iteration to execute. In order to increase the speed of this for loop, what should I do? Use `asyncio`, `multiprocessing`? My idea for increasing the execution speed is to have the next iteration of the loop begin when `huge_method` is called and have both iterations run at the same time. Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Example of what I mean:

```
for i in range(len(some_list)):
    x = some_list[i]['model']
    y = some_other_list[i]['prediction']
    result = huge_method(x, y) # This is what's taking up most of the time in this loop
    # some more code...
    list_of_results.append(result)
```

**Note**: anything calculated during an individual iteration is not dependent on anything calculated in a previous iteration. Also, each iteration appends a result to a list. Maintaining the order of each iterations results is important but I can make it work otherwise. What I'm referring to as `huge_method` here is a method from a 3rd party library and not code I would like to modify.

**Edit:** For clarity, here is the actual code I'm working with:

```
for ii_day in range(len(prediction_indices)):
    model_idx = prediction_indices[ii_day]["model_idx"]
    prediction_idx = prediction_indices[ii_day]["prediction_idx"]

    # Fit model
    regression_period_signal = historical_signal_levels[model_idx, :]
    regression_period_price_change = historical_price_moves[model_idx]
          try:
             # This is the huge_method that takes half the time of an iteration
             rolling_regression_model = LinearRegression().fit(regression_period_signal, regression_period_price_change)
             self.coef_list.append(rolling_regression_model.coef_) 

             # Calculate model error
             predictions = rolling_regression_model.predict(regression_period_signal)
             forecast_horizon_model_error = np.sqrt(
                            mean_squared_error(regression_period_price_change, predictions))

             # Predictions
             forecast_distance = 1
             current_research = historical_signal_levels[prediction_idx, :]
             forecast_price_change = rolling_regression_model.predict(current_research)
                      
             # Calculate drift and volatility
             volatility = ((1 + forecast_horizon_model_error) * (forecast_distance ** -0.5)) - 1

             # Kelly recommended optimum
             if volatility < 0:
                raise ZeroDivisionError("Volatility needs to be positive value.")
             if volatility == 0:
                volatility = 0.01

             kelly_recommended_optimum = forecast_price_change / volatility ** 2
             rule_recommended_allocation = self.kelly_fraction * kelly_recommended_optimum
          except:
             rule_recommended_allocation = np.zeros(len(prediction_idx))
    # Apply the calculated allocation to the dataframe.
    price_research_series.loc[prediction_idx, position_key] = rule_recommended_allocation
```

Comment: If `huge_method` is doing work (and not just waiting on I/O), that rules out `asyncio`, and `threading` unless you're on a implementation without a GIL, so then there's multiprocessing. That loop looks like essentially a map over `some_list` and `some_other_list` zipped together. Something like: `with Pool() as p: results = p.starmap(huge_method, zip(some_list, some_other_list))`, where `Pool` is `from multiprocessing.pool import Pool`.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7.3.. If I were to use the `starmap()` method of `Pool`, wouldn't it then iterate over every possible combination of `some_list` and `some_other_list` indices?

Comment: No. `starmap` is like `map`, except it "spreads" the passed data as multiple arguments. That line would be the same as `p.map(lambda pair: huge_method(pair[0], pair[1]), zip(some_list, some_other_list))`.

Comment: Gotcha. In any case, I don't think I can iterate directly over the lists using `zip` because they're lists of DataFrames. Sorry for not specifying earlier. I will post the actual code in an edit.

Comment: Even if you can't use `map` directly, you can submit jobs to the pool using other methods like `apply_async`, and just keep the loop you have.

Comment: Hey this worked! Thanks :)

Comment: Np. Glad to help.